# SEO - Adding META ARCHIVE and GOOGLEBOT

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, meta-tags

I've been looking around at different ecommerce websites and I noticed that a lot of them have the following meta information:

**PART 1**

Magento only has the option to set pages as `INDEX, FOLLOW`, how would I add `INDEX, ARCHIVE, FOLLOW` as part of the options?

**PART 2**

How can I add a seperate META for `GOOGLEBOT` or other specific bots to try and increase indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1**

If you want set it from config you have to add an extension that sets another sourcemodel for for robots config section ...

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <design>
            <groups>
                <head>
                    <fields>
                        <default_robots translate="label">
                            <!-- <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_design_robots</source_model> -->
                            <source_model>your/source_model</source_model>
```

Then your source model should extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Design_Robots` and `toOptionArray()` could look like ...

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $options = parent::toOptionArray();
    $options[] = array('value'=>'NOARCHIVE', 'label'=>'NOARCHIVE');
    return $options;
}
```

Or you set it from your layout.xml ...

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><value>NOARCHIVE</value></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_index>
```

**Part 2**

> The robots meta tag applies to all search engines, while the "googlebot" meta tag is specific to Google. ([Source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en))

So this should work ... but you have to modify your head.phtml

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="..., ..." />
```